# Cant reference passed value attribute in returned html code

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm sure I'm doing something dumb but I don't see why this code wont work. It's react code that I'm compiling with webpack:

```
  var markers = this.state.assets;
      assets = assets.map(function(asseti,index){
        return(
          asseti.map(function(asset, index){
            return(
              <Marker position=[{asset.location.coordinates[0]},{asset.location.coordinates[1]}]>
                <Popup>
                  <span>A pretty CSS3 popup.<br/>Easily customizable.</span>
                </Popup>
              </Marker>

            )
          })
        )
      });
```

I get the error

```
JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text

  90 |           asseti.map(function(asset, index){
  91 |             return(
> 92 |               <Marker position=[{asset.location.coordinates[0]},{asset.location.coordinates[1]}]>
     |                                ^
  93 |                 <Popup>
  94 |                   <span>A pretty CSS3 popup.<br/>Easily customizable.</span>
  95 |                 </Popup>
```

Thanks, Ed.

Comment: What do you expect `{asset.location.coordinates[0]}` to mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass props arrays wrapped within `{}`  as it is a JS expression

i.e `position={[asset.location.coordinates[0],asset.location.coordinates[1]]}`

```
 markers = this.state.assets;
  assets = assets.map(function(asseti,index){
    return(
      asseti.map(function(asset, index){
        return(
          <Marker position={[asset.location.coordinates[0],asset.location.coordinates[1]]}>
            <Popup>
              <span>A pretty CSS3 popup.<br/>Easily customizable.</span>
            </Popup>
          </Marker>

        )
      })
    )
  });
```

Comment: It now throws the error: `Unexpected token, expected , (92:40)

  90 |            asseti.map(function(asset, index){
  91 |              return(
> 92 |                <Marker position={[{asset.location.coordinates[0]},{asset.location.coordinates[1]}]}>
     |                                         ^
  93 |                  <Popup>
  94 |                    <span>A pretty CSS3 popup.<br/>Easily customizable.</span>
  95 |                  </Popup>`

Comment: Also remove the `{}` inside the array elements. Updated the question

Comment: Works like a charm, your are amazing and an awesome person!

Comment: glad to have helped Ed, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So this isn't valid JSX.  Try the below instead.  I would have to see what position is looking to accept to help further.

```
<Marker position={[asset.location.coordinates[0], asset.location.coordinates[1]]}>
                <Popup>
                  <span>A pretty CSS3 popup.<br/>Easily customizable.</span>
                </Popup>
              </Marker>
```

Comment: `{asset.location.coordinates[0]}` is not valid JS.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you are returning in your render function make sure the result is wrapped in some element. You can't return an array of components in your render function as it looks like now